# how to sort inside the object and subtract the values inside the objects in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Input documents

```
  "data": {
    "2021-05-05": {
      "12": 2.1,
      "15": 0.2,
      "06": 2.6,
      "09": 2.2
    },
    "2021-05-06": {
      "12": 2.1,
      "15": 0.2,
      "06": 2,
      "09": 1.7
    }
}
```

Intermediate step data `objects` will be concatenated with keys and sort it with respect to time.

```
  "data": {
    "2021-05-05": {
      "2021-05-05T06:00:00:0Z": 2.6,
      "2021-05-05T09:00:00:0Z": 2.2,
      "2021-05-05T12:00:00:0Z": 2.1,
      "2021-05-05T15:00:00:0Z": 0.2

    },
    "2021-05-06": {
      "2021-05-06T12:00:00:0Z": 2.1,
    }
}
```

After sorting. the next step would be. `Subtract` from the `value_last` - `value_first` with respect to time.

Output document

`Document 1`

```
{
  "data": {
      "time_first" : "2021-05-05T06:00:00:0Z",
      "value_first": 2.6,
      "time_last": "2021-05-05T15:00:00:0Z"
      "value_last": "0.2",
      "difference_value_last-value_first" : -0.4

    }
```

`Document 2`  if contain only one value, the previous month value_last become `value_first`  of the next document.

```
    "data": {
      "time_first" : "2021-05-05T15:00:00:0Z",
      "value_first": 0.2,
      "time_last":  "2021-05-06T12:00:00:0Z",
      "value_last": : 2.1 ,
      "difference_value_last-value_first" : 1.9
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregations

- `$objectToArray` to make object to an array, so we can get key:value pair which has defined name "k" that helps to get data
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$sort` to sort by the condition
- `$group` to find the first and last element that we sort
- `$concat` to concat the string date time string

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {  $project: { data: { "$objectToArray": "$data} } },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          in: {
            "dk": "$$this.k",
            "dv": { "$objectToArray": "$$this.v" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { $unwind: "$data.dv" },
  {
    $sort: {
      "data.dk": -1,
      "data.dv.v": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$data.dk",
      firstData: { $first: "$data.dv"  },
      lastData: { $last: "$data.dv" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "time_first": {
        $concat: [ "$_id", "T", "$firstData.k", ":00:00:0Z" ]
      },
      "time_last": {
        $concat: [ "$_id", "T", "$lastData.k", ":00:00:0Z" ]
      },
      "value_first": "$firstData.v",
      "value_last": "$lastData.v",
      "difference_value_last-value_first": {
        "$subtract": [ "$lastData.v", "$firstData.v" ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vgc8nmohbuj)**